# Why is my slider not working?

Tags: jquery, html, css, unslider

Console is returning no errors.

Using [Unslider](http://unslider.com).

I have:

```
   <div class="slider">
       <ul>
        <li><img src="img/one.jpg" alt=""></li>
        <li><img src="img/one.jpg" alt=""></li>
        <li><img src="img/one.jpg" alt=""></li>
        <li><img src="img/one.jpg" alt=""></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
```

Then calling it with:

```
<script src="dist/js/unslider-min.js"></script>
<script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $('.slider').unslider();
        });
</script>
```

All the files are linked correctly.

Live version is [here](http://makeeers.com).

Comment: Well... is Jquery loaded?

Comment: @Terry but wouldn't that throw an error in console if he hadn't?

Comment: @terry Using a CDN and a file is linked.

Comment: The css is not being properly applied to ur controls, please check again

Comment: @AhsN just realised that the CSS files are not loading. Looking into it now.

Answer (score 0):

Issue occured because css files were incorrecctly linked.